# Conditional Labels, Multiple Labels ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript

I'm attempting to write a code to show 6 fields that all have some Null values. The fields will have accompanying text labels that are not a field, and each one needs to be on a different line.

The 6 fields are [TF] [INV] [INV_N] [INV_S] [INV_E] [INV_W] 
The desired output would be 
"TF [TF]"
"INV [INV]" 
etc.

I have tried to do research and can't seem to find anything with this many values. The vb-script code I *attempted* to write is:

```vb
    Function FindLabel ( [TF], [INV], [INV_N] , [INV_S] , [INV_E] , [INV_W]  )
     FindLabel = "TF " & [TF] & vbCrLf  
      If IsNull( [INV] ) Then
     FindLabel = ( [INV_N] )
      If isNull ( [INV_N] ) Then
     FindLabel = ( [INV_S] )
      If isNull ( [INV_S] ) Then
    FindLabel =( [INV_E] )
     If isNull ( [INV_W] ) Then
    Else
     FindLabel = "INV " & [INV] &vbCrLf
    Else 
     FindLabel = "INV N " & [INV_N] & vbCrLf
    Else
     FindLabel = "INV S " & [INV_S] & vbCrLf
    Else
     FindLabel = "INV E " & [INV_E] & vbCrLf
    Else
     FindLabel = "INV W " & [INV_W] 
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
   End Function
```

My coding experience is 1 Java class my freshman year of college so I'm pretty lost when it comes to this.

If the field has a `Null` I would not want the text to be shown nor for there to be an empty space

Comment: If you're starting mostly from scratch as far as coding goes, I'd suggest using Python instead of VB, VB has no future in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep your `if` and `end if` together, checking for `Null` each time.  If it's `Null` then do nothing (move to the next field), and if it's not `Null` then add the relevant text and value.

```vb
Function FindLabel ([TF], [INV], [INV_N], [INV_S], [INV_E], [INV_W])

FindLabel = "TF = " & ([TF])

if not isNull([INV]) Then
 FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline & "INV = " & ([INV])
end if
if not isNull([INV_N]) Then
 FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline & "INV_N = " & ([INV_N])
end if
if not isNull([INV_S]) Then
 FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline & "INV_S = " & ([INV_S])
end if
if not isNull([INV_E]) Then
 FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline & "INV_E = " & ([INV_E])
end if
if not isNull([INV_W]) Then
 FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline & "INV_W = " & ([INV_W])
end if

End Function
```

All this does is take the `FindLabel` string and adds to it when there's a value to add, constructing a longer string to output as the label.  If all of them are `Null` it will only output the `TF` value.

---

As recommended in @DanC's comment, you should look into using Python for your labelling as VBScript is being phased out.

Change the Label Parser to Python (at the bottom of the Label Expression window), switch to Advanced and try this code:

```py
def FindLabel ( [TF], [INV], [INV_N] , [INV_S] , [INV_E] , [INV_W]   ):
  myLabel = "TF = {0}".format([TF])
  if not [INV] is None:
    myLabel += "\nINV = {0}".format([INV])
  if not [INV_N] is None:
    myLabel += "\nINV_N = {0}".format([INV_N])
  if not [INV_S] is None:
    myLabel += "\nINV_S = {0}".format([INV_S])
  if not [INV_E] is None:
    myLabel += "\nINV_E = {0}".format([INV_E])
  if not [INV_W] is None:
    myLabel += "\nINV_W = {0}".format([INV_W])
  return myLabel
```

**NOTE:** Python *requires* consistent indents, so be careful that everything is indented correctly.

Comment: Smashing stuff. This will come in very useful.

Answer (score -1):

Use Python

[image]

Here's the expression

```
def FindLabel ( [TF], [INV], [INV_N] , [INV_S] , [INV_E] , [INV_W] ):
  return "TF: " + [TF] + "\nINV: " + [INV] + "\nINV_N: " + [INV_N] + "\nINV_S: " + [INV_S] + "\nINV_E: " + [INV_E] + "\nINV_W: " + [INV_W]
```

This will stake your labels. The + is concatenation and the \n means place what follows on a newline.

If any of these are numeric values you need to cast to string with str()
example

```
str(TF)
```

Turn on Maplex Engine if you want to left justify.

Comment: I missed that you didn't want to show if the value was NULL. I'll update

Comment: [str.format()](https://pyformat.info/)